# Generalization of Thorne integral

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, integration, gravitational-waves, multipole-expansion

How can we generalize the integral expressions given by Thorne in [his paper  in equation (2.5)? The formula given in his paper cannot be directly translated to terms that has similar structure but not exact.  (https://blackholes.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/gritting/pdf/gravitational_waves/Thorne_Multipole-expansions-of-gravitational-radiation.pdf)

There could be integrals of the form,

$$ \int d^2 \Omega \, \frac{1}{4\pi} n^c n^q N^{L-2} \epsilon_{cd}^{(i} V^{j)}_{d L-2}  N^{P-2} \epsilon_{qr(i} V_{j) d P-2} $$

Here `n^c` is a unit vector in spherical coordinates and the tensor `N^L = n^{l1} n^l2 ... n^{l_L}`. It is just the product of `n` vectors.
What would be the corresponding result of such an integral where V is a symmetric trace-free tensor independent of angular dependence?

Comment: Please do not delete & repost [closed questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/771657/25301). You need to make the appropriate edits to the original. If you need help on that, please post a question on the matter on [Physics Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Adding to the above comment: You did the right thing when you edited the other question, and it was enqueued for reopen review automatically. However, this site does not work in real-time, and you deleted the question before the reopen review could be completed.